# Which Functional programming language offers best support in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, programming-languages, eclipse-plugin, functional-programming

As an exercise my team is looking at learning functional programming. One of the factors to choose a language is its support in Eclipse. Any language with Eclipse plug-in is fine but what language offers the best free plug-in?

Bonus question: the best online/book tutorial for this language.

Comment: Just added the online book reference to my answer.

Comment: I added Python/PyDev answer as I find both the language and its support in Eclipse a viable option.

Comment: My 2 cents: if you really want to learn functional programming then you should pick a real functional language. Python or JavaScript, as suggested in some answers, are not even close. Scala is better, but still makes it somewhat hard to see the elegance of FP. I'd _strongly_ suggest sticking to some dialect of ML/Ocaml, Haskell, or Scheme/Lisp. IDE support should be a secondary concern for this purpose.

Comment: @AndreasRossberg - if any of the options you listed come with IDE plugin for Eclipse (or even independent IDE) it would make a valid answer to my question, thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't know if it is the best, but it is evolving and improving fast:

[**Scala IDE**](http://www.scala-ide.org/) (up to [Scala2.8.1RC1](http://www.scala-ide.org/2010/09/the-scala-ide-for-eclipse-for-scala-2-8-1-rc1-available-now/) right now)

[image]

---

As for the best online Scala book:

[Programming Scala](http://programming-scala.labs.oreilly.com/) ([Creative Commons Attribution-Noncommercial](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc/3.0/))

[image]

But you will find other online sources in the SO question "[List of freely available programming books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194812/list-of-freely-available-programming-books/392926#392926)".

Answer (score 2):

Clojure is pretty well supported with the [Counterclockwise](http://code.google.com/p/counterclockwise/) plugin in Eclipse. Key features:

- A nice syntax aware editor including rainbow braces
- An integrated REPL
- Dependency management orks reasonably nicely with Maven, other Eclipse plugins etc.
- Debug mode works fairly well

Comment: Loved Lisp back at college and short time with AutoCAD. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I would go for Javascript, with Eclipse + Aptana plug-in and [Secrets of the Javascript Ninja](http://jsninja.com/) for a book with some nice advanced material.

Comment: +1 for reminding me of JavaScript as functional programming language option and for referencing excellent resource. I have seen other post here recommending it for beginners in functional programming.

Comment: Add node.js into the mix and this becomes a really interesting option.

Answer (score 0):

Since nobody gave this answer I have to add it.

Groovy offers Java integration, Eclipse plugin and integration, and functional features. Many would argue that it's a scripting language but it's a complete language nonetheless. And it's obvious choice for Java junkies...

Comment: Community version of IDEA offers superior than Eclipse plugin for Groovy and is definitely worth checking out.

Answer (score 0):

Python with PyDev plugin is another great option.

Answer (score 0):

Erlide plugin for Erlang development on Eclipse.